# Does a CompletableFuture completes on a re-thrown exception?

Tags: spring, java-8, completable-future

I've just started using  CompletableFuture and already loving it.

But one strange thing that appears to me while using a CompletableFuture is its method called "exceptionally"

Let's say I've a
`CompletableFuture<?> cf1.`

Now, once the data arrives, my code is applying some processing logic. In case of an exception, I make use of exceptionally method to rethrow `MyCustomException`

```
cf1  
.thenApply(myData->Some Processing Logic)  
.exceptionally(ex-> throw new MyCustomException())

cf.get();
```

Interestingly, the call to get method hangs indefinitely until I terminate the program. Does that mean that if a CompletableFuture re-throws an exception from the exceptionally block, the future will not be marked as complete? Do I need to explicity mark it as complete?

Comment: There is no `cf` in your code snippet. And the result of `exceptionally` is not assigned to any variable at all. Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From docs the [get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get--) method throws exception if the future completed exceptionally

> ExecutionException - if this future completed exceptionally

So either you can return some value from `exceptionally` to identify the exception is thrown during `thenApply` and call `get` method for value

Second way, before calling `get` method you can make that future object completed using [allOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-), and check if the future is completed exceptionally

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFuture);
completableFuture.isCompletedExceptionally();  //true
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I've tried returning the value from ````exceptionally```` and it works well. But the alternative way of using completablefuture. Is Completed Exceptionally again hanged indefinitely.

Comment: What is the purpose of the statement `CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFuture);`? As it is written here, it has no effect at all—except for a small slowdown in some cases due to performing an obsolete operation unless the JIT eliminates it.

Comment: As per my understanding if `Main` thread don't wait until async completableFuture complete, and if main thread check if future is completed exceptionally that it will always return false right ? correct me @Holger if i'm wrong

Comment: Sure, if `completableFuture` has not been completed, the check `completableFuture.isCompletedExceptionally()` will return `false`. The statement `CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFuture);` will not change that. It creates a new future that will be completed when all of the supplied arguments are completed, but you don’t use the result. So it just slows down the execution a bit but if that causes the completion of the original future in the meanwhile, it’s pure luck. You need to wait for the completion of `allOf`’s result but then, why not wait for the completion of `completableFuture`…

Comment: okay that's good point to know, but is there any method to make future object to wait until process is completed ? i know there is `join` but i don't think it works to wait @Holger

Comment: Both, `get` and `join` will wait for the completion. But they will also throw an exception if the future has been completed exceptionally. If you just want to wait for the completion without needing to catch an exception, you could use `completableFuture.exceptionally(x -> null).join()` which will wait and not throw (under normal circumstances). Then, you could check `completableFuture .isCompletedExceptionally()`. But that’s not the problem here. The OP claimed that `get` will hang forever, which is unsolvable without a [mcve], as any “wait for completion” should have the same behavior.

Comment: Thank you @Holger that's the first approach i recommended to OP, but i don't know about OP question `get` is being hand forever which doesn't happened in my system, But i want to provide some recommended patterns in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Heres a sample code that doesnot finish on throwing exception -

```
CompletableFuture<String> r1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            throw new RuntimeException("blahh !!!");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });

    CompletableFuture<String> r2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "55");
    CompletableFuture<String> r3 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "56");
    CompletableFuture.allOf(r1, r2, r3).thenRun(() -> { System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+" --- End."); });
    Stream.of(r1, r2, r3).forEach(System.out::println);


    try{
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+" --- SLEEPING !!!");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+" --- DONE !!!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Stream.of(r1, r2, r3).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).